# TSQL Recursive Concatenate Nested Navigation Names

Tags: t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have tried to find an example on Stack Overflow that works for me but I can not find it. I am trying to recursively concatenate the parents of each node in a table which hold parent/child nodes. Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL_EXAMPLE (
    PARENT_NAV_ID INT,
    NAV_ID INT,
    NAV_NAME VARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO #TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES(NULL, 1, 'MILKY WAY')
INSERT INTO #TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES(1, 2, 'SOLAR SYSTEM')
INSERT INTO #TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES(3, 4, 'EARTH')
INSERT INTO #TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES(4, 5, 'ANTARCTICA')

; WITH #EXAMPLE_CTE AS (
    SELECT
        PARENT_NAV_ID,
        NAV_ID,
        NAV_NAME,
        CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NAV_PARENT_NAME
    FROM #TBL_EXAMPLE
        WHERE PARENT_NAV_ID IS NULL
    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        EXMP.PARENT_NAV_ID,
        EXMP.NAV_ID,
        EXMP.NAV_NAME,
        CT.NAV_PARENT_NAME + '/' + EXMP.NAV_NAME AS PARENT_NAV_NAME
    FROM #TBL_EXAMPLE EXMP
        INNER JOIN #EXAMPLE_CTE CT ON EXMP.PARENT_NAV_ID = CT.NAV_ID
)
SELECT
*
FROM #EXAMPLE_CTE
```

What I get is this:

```
PARENT_NAV_ID   NAV_ID  NAV_NAME        NAV_PARENT_NAME
NULL            1       MILKY WAY   
1               2       SOLAR SYSTEM    /SOLAR SYSTEM
```

What I want it this:

```
PARENT_NAV_ID   NAV_ID  NAV_NAME        NAV_PARENT_NAME
NULL            1       MILKY WAY       MILKY WAY
1               2       SOLAR SYSTEM    MILKY WAY/SOLAR SYSTEM
3               4       EARTH           MILKY WAY/SOLAR SYSTEM/EARTH
4               5       ANTARCTICA      MILKY WAY/SOLAR SYSTEM/EARTH/ANTARCTICA
```

I know I am missing some fundamental understanding of how CTEs work but I have come across something that makes it clear to me. What can I look at next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not in the recursion, but in your sample data. There is no parent "3". Try

```
INSERT INTO #TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES(NULL, 1, 'MILKY WAY')
INSERT INTO #TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES(1, 2, 'SOLAR SYSTEM')
INSERT INTO #TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES(2, 3, 'EARTH')
INSERT INTO #TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES(3, 4, 'ANTARCTICA')
```

Just tried it: It comes back with the result you want, except the first "MILKY WAY" under "NAV_PARENT_NAME". Change this

```
CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NAV_PARENT_NAME
```

to

```
CAST(NAV_NAME AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NAV_PARENT_NAME
```

Comment: To be honest: a person being able to write recursive CTEs surely is **not** stupid :-) Happy coding!